# How to make efficient INSERT query in php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am using php to insert element values of a form in MYSQL. My form contains 20 different elements, that means

```
count($_POST)
```

returns 20. How can I make an INSERT query efficiently in PHP.

Comment: How can you make it inefficiently? Do you have any solution that works, but works slow for your task?

Comment: Please give us more information.

Comment: Could you add some extra information to your question?

Comment: I will extract 20 values one by one then concatenate them again one by one. I do not want to follow this method. Do you have some better method?

Comment: @Mayank Gupta: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html - you can insert several records in a single query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will extract 20 values one by one then concatenate them again one by
>   one. I do not want to follow this method. Do you have some better
>   method?

Yes, you can use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Example below assumes 3 thigs:

- all of your form fields are text fields,
- form fields are in the same order as columns in your table
- form elements (`<input>`) have the same `name` attribute as columns names in your table

It can go like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    $sql .= mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
$sql .= ')';
```